# Read last n elements of an XML file with Linq XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, file, listview

I am using the follow Code to read an XML file:

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);

        foreach (var node in doc.Descendants("LogInfo"))
        {

            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[]
            {
                node.Element("MailBox").Value,
                node.Element("LastRun").Value,
            });
            listViewHome.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

How can I change this Code to receive just the last "n" number of elements from that XML file?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var nodes = doc.Descendants("LogInfo");
foreach (var node in nodes.Skip(Items.Count() - n))
{
    ...
}
```

Or this:

```
var nodes = doc.Descendants("LogInfo");
foreach (var node in nodes.Reverse().Take(n).Reverse())
{
    ...
}
```

If you're feeling adventurous, you could also write your own [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) which should be more efficient than either of these. Here's my quick and dirty solution:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeFromEnd<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int n)
{
    var arry = new T[n];
    int i = 0;
    foreach(var x in items)
    {
        arry[i++ % n] = x;
    }

    if (i < n)
    {
        n = i;
        i = 0;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        yield return arry[(i + j) % n];
    }
}

var nodes = doc.Descendants("LogInfo");
foreach (var node in nodes.TakeFromEnd(n))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1. The only issue I have with the two answers is that `Count()` will traverse once and `Skip().Take()` another time. While LINQ express this problem very well, it is not the most optimal answer.

Comment: @pswg Say you have 10 items but want to take the last 3, Reverse will traverse all 10, then the last 3 twice (so that's `Count + 2*Take`). If you `Skip(Count() - Take)`, you traverse 10 for the `Count` and another 10 (7 for the `Skip`, 3 for the `Take`). I think Reverse might be more effective but since it's all in memory, the difference won't be noticeable.

Comment: Many, many thanks, brilliant idea... have to wait 4min to click on accept this for answer... will be afk now and do that later ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
var logs = doc.Descendants("LogInfo");
var logsCount = logs.Count();

foreach (var node in logs.Skip(logsCount - n).Take(n))
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[]
    {
        node.Element("MailBox").Value,
        node.Element("LastRun").Value,
    });
    listViewHome.Items.Add(item);
}
```

And here is XPath solution, which will enumerate xml once

```
var xpath = String.Format("//LogInfo[position()>last()-{0}]", n);
foreach (var log in doc.XPathSelectElements(xpath))
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[]
    {
        (string)log.Element("MailBox"),
        (string)log.Element("LastRun")
    });
    listViewHome.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Well, +1 for an XPath solution. Haven't seen those in a while.

Comment: I tried it with that XPath solution but I do not get any data back... The listview is empty...

Comment: @Simon just verified, it works without problems. Make sure that you have `using System.Xml.XPath;` at the top of file - extensions defined in that namespace